# How to have 2 set of radio groups in a dialog box in android

Tags: android, radio-button, dialog, radio-group

Is there any way to create a dialogbox with 2 set of radio groups other than creating a custom dialog box through layout.

I mean I want to have 2 independent set of radio groups (each has 3 radio buttons) in a dialog box with out creating layout.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not way to have 2 set of radio groups with default Dialogs. 
You're only way is to create a custom dialog with a custom layout.
The only function with radio button is setSingleChoiceItems and there no other way. setMultipleChoiceItems use checkbox only and have no groups

Sorry

Comment: You're welcome. You can find a lot of tutorial for creating custom dialog. This one for example http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/